# Angular: prevent user from clicking buttton more than once

Tags: angular, firebase, events, button

I have this small moviesDB app with firebase. If you search the movie in the home page, youll'see results retrieved from this open API and now you are in a detailed page via routing. In this page you can send reviews to a collection in firebase and like the movie (all in the same node):

[image]

My issue: prevent the user to like the same movie more than once. So far I have this:

Like Component HTML:

```
<button [disabled]="plus>1" (click)="increase()" class="btn btn-success">Like this Movie!</button>
```

Like TS:

```
export class LikeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change=new EventEmitter()
  plus:number=1;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

increase(){

  this.change.emit({like:this.plus++})
}
```

The detail HTML where I fetch the event:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <form [formGroup]="reviewForm" (ngSubmit)="submitReview()">
    <label for="review">Write your review!</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" formControlName="review"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="reviewForm.invalid && likeable"  type="submit">Send review</button>
  </form>
  <app-like style="float:right" (change)="onChange($event)"></app-like>
  </div>
```

And the TS:

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  userReviews:any;
  userName:string;
  likes:any;
  constructor(
    private movieService: MoviesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private location: Location,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private localService: LocalService  ) {

      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        this.userName = user.displayName;
      })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap(params => {
          this.id = params.get("title");
          return this.movieService.getMovies(this.id);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.movie = data
        //etc
  }

reviews(){
  this.reviewForm= this.fb.group({
    review: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}
get userReview(){return this.reviewForm.get('review')}

onChange(event){
  this.likes=event
}

submitReview(){
  if(this.likes===undefined){ //->firebase doesnt accept undefined
    this.likes=null
  }
let credentials = {
  author: this.userName,
  review: this.userReview.value,
  movie: this.id,
  likes: this.likes
}


  this.movieService.createReview(credentials).then(data=>{
    console.log(data)
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

So as you can see, the LIKE button is only available if the `plus` variable has more than one vote. It works, actually, but as I refresh the page or leave and get back, the button is available again. How can I work this around? Any thoughts? Thanks

EDIT (answer based on @JBoothUA hint)

I have implmented like this

```
export class LikeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change=new EventEmitter()
  plus:number=1;
  local:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("plus"));
  }

increase(){
localStorage.setItem('plus', JSON.stringify( this.plus++))
  this.change.emit({like:this.plus++})
}
```

But no results. After refresing the the button is available again. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 2 @JBoothUA, @Rahul Tokase and @Shravan

Everything works now with ths code:

```
export class LikeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter()
  plus: number = 1;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  this.plus = +localStorage.getItem('plus')

  }

  increase() {
    localStorage.setItem('plus',''+ ++this.plus)
    this.change.emit({ like: this.plus++ })
  }
```

But now, well its pretty logical, now the user cannot vote any other movie, like he has only one vote foe rhousands of movies. I guess I have to associate this with the particular movie he has voted for. How am I going to achieve that? Is this the right path or the whole thing should be redone?

Comment: You should be storing the value is `plus` variable. You generally JSON.stringify objects and not primitive datatypes. Instead for storing the value, you should be doing like this `localStorage.setItem('plus', ++this.plus)`. And while retrieveing the value, you should be doing like this `this.plus = +localStorage.getItem('plus')`. The '+' sign is to convert string to number.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a way for Angular to automatically store state during a refresh.  So you would have to find another way to store the variable, as Angular will clear its memory on a refresh.

You could use something like a db or a redis cache.

I would look into storing that value as Local Storage, Session Storage, or a cookie.

Example:

```
let key = 'Item 1';
localStorage.setItem(key, 'Value');
let myItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

localStorage and sessionStorage accomplish the exact same thing and have the same API, but with sessionStorage the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with localStorage the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.

Comment: you say store the plus variable in localstorage?  In the like component, right? or does the moment wehere you store it makes the difference

Comment: local storage is the BROWSERS storage.  the moment shouldn't make a difference.  Angular / Component code will store all the values in memory and they will be cleared out on a refresh.  However, the BROWSER's local storage or session storage will NOT be cleared out.

Comment: edited my answer with some more details. hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You have the following two ways to do this.
1) Have a backend API which will give the like status and depending upon the status you can disabled the like button.
2) You can make a use of LocalStorage or SessionStorage tp store the state.
3) Make a use of NgRx Store to store the state.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Ok guys, ill try the local storage aproach, thanks!

Comment: @Mellville localStorage approach is not the correct way. What if the user decides to use your web app from different PC or from a different browser in the same PC? In that case, the button will be active again and the user can like the same movie again. It is a bad practice to use localStorage to manage the state of the app across multiple sessions.

Comment: yes, I understand your point and you're right; but how would you solve this?

Comment: As per the option 1 specified in this answer, you have to fetch the like counts of the current user for this movie during `ngOnInit` and disable the button. A better appriach would be to use a combination of localStorage strategy (store plus counts and retrieve from localStorage in the same session) and backend API call strategy (to get the plus count from firebase on reload of page).